# pandas to_excel not working with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyinstaller, pandas.excelwriter

I'm making an exe from a python script using `pyinstaller` everything in the code works fine except for `to_excel()`. I've listed the imports and what exactly is not working when I make it an exe. Script runs on its own and creates excel file the problem is file is not created if i make it an exe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import camelot
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import requests
import urllib.request
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import shutil
import glob
import math
import datetime
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

pg_main_data.to_excel('final_analysis.xlsx')
grouped_summary.to_excel('analysis_summary.xlsx')
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I dont get any error the exe closes but the file is not being written

Comment: Does the code work well when you are running it in a console (not packaged with `pyinstaller`)?

Comment: It might be irrelevant but please check your working directory, because you should have seen errors if something gone wrong.

Comment: yes the script runs fine in console as for exe just to_excel() is not working

Comment: @adolfsingh: as a token of appreciation could you please mark one of the answers as accepted (gray tick on the left of the answer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the `pandas` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html) specifies, in order for `to_excel` and `read_excel` methods to work you have to install one or more of the following packages alongside `pandas`:

```
XLsxWriter  0.9.8  Excel writing
openpyxl  2.5.7 Reading / writing for xlsx files
pyxlsb   1.0.6  Reading for xlsb files
xlrd   1.1.0   Excel reading
xlwt   1.2.0   Excel writing
```

Depending on your setup you might have not installed them or you might have not included them in `pyinstaller` list of packages.

Comment: Im using an anaconda environment i have xlsxwriter installed in it if i add `import xlsxwriter` in the script will it work?

Comment: You can always give it a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

to read and write from excel you need to install `xlwt` (to write in `xls` format), `openpyxl`(to write in `xlsx` format) `xlrd` (to `read` excel)

install all these dependencies using:

```
pip install xlwt openpyxl xlrd
```

Comment: the script is working well problem arises when i make it an exe will this solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I use the pandas read_excel function to read the excel file.

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('Yourdata.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheetname')

data.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I guess right, this problem has not been resolved. I have the same issue. File updates(xlsm) but in Temp/MEIPASS folder, does not bring it to bundled folder